# iOS app opens deep link only once

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, deep-linking

I'm using the following function to deep link:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool{
    if(url.host == "dl"){
        window?.rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("DeepLinkSegue", sender: nil)
        print("DL-VC opened!")
    }

    return true
}
```

When typing myapp://dl in Safari browser it should open the ViewController with the segue identifier „DeepLinkSegue“. That works fine, the ViewController opens.

But only once after launching the app. When you go to an other VC and try again to open the specific VC with „myapp://dl“ just the app opens, not the specific VC. You have to restart the app otherwise it won’t work and just opens the app not the specific VC.

I first thought the function is maybe called only once. But not so because print("DL-VC opened!") always prints. There's no error on the console, just: DL-VC opened!

**Here's the project to reproduce the problem: http://www.filedropper.com/deeplinktest**

**The Question below is already solved!**

In addition the app crashes when opening the deep link on first launch, just after install. Console shows up this:

```
2016-06-04 15:41:39.437 MyApp[3009:1380697] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MyApp.Introduction: 0x15f5c4d70>) has no segue with identifier 'PushSegue''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18353edb0 0x182ba3f80 0x188a15ca8 0x100012a38 0x1000123b8 0x18894da80 0x18894d4f0 0x188955f48 0x18895c684 0x18895ba80 0x18894570c 0x188945394 0x184edf7ac 0x184edf618 0x184edf9c8 0x1834f509c 0x1834f4b30 0x1834f2830 0x18341cc50 0x184d04088 0x188706088 0x100012670 0x182fba8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Does anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Regards,
David.

Comment: For question 1, I'd print the values of `window` and `window?.rootViewController` to see if there were hints.  The error in the second part is very specific.  Are you using a segue called 'PushSegue' in a controller called `Introduction`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check this out an get back.

Comment: The second problem is solved. Thank you. The reason is hard to explain.

Comment: For the crash you are doing this performSegueWithIdentifier("PushSegue", sender: nil) this is causing the crash because their is no link in storyboard fix that.

Comment: Using this `print(window?.rootViewController)` and this `print(window)`, output is: `Optional(<MyApp.Introduction: 0x14d5cdec0>)` and `Optional(<UIWindow: 0x14d57af30; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14d56d200>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x14d56e480>>)`

Comment: @PhillipMills Can you detect any hints?

Comment: Here's the project to reproduce the problem: http://www.filedropper.com/deeplinktest